# Can't connect to JMS using restricted user via GEMS

Tags: jms

I have user (not administrator) access to some external JMS.
I'm failing to view queue while trying to use GEMS.
My guess this is because GEMS is admin console for JMS but user I have don't have any administrator permissions.
I've made a try to create user without admin permissions on my local Tibco and I fail to connect to JMS using very user in GEMS.

How could I view any JMS with resricted user? Is GEMS able to do that? If not what tools could be used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Hermes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hermesjms) tool suitable for this.
It was relly hard to get Hermes working with Tibco EMS. [Here](http://tibcoadmin.com/tibco/ems/configuring-hermesjms-for-tibco-ems/) is good tutorial how to configure Hermes.

---

HermesJMS provides a GUI to access JMS queues and topics for common tasks such as sending messages, removing messages and copying messages between queues and topics. It’s one of some “must have” tools for EMS admins and application support team.

Get the latest installer from SourceForge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/hermesjms/files/ then run it:
java -jar hermes-installer.jar

Installation is very simple, just few screens: release notes, license agreement, installation path, components (here is only one actually), summary, files copying, shortcuts creation and installation finish.

To start HermesJMS run hermes.bat in your \HermesJMS\bin. If you got error message “cannot find \bin\javaw”, make sure that you have JAVA_HOME system variable defined to your jre folder.

When Hermes started successfully, click on “Create new JMS session” button, preferences window will appear, select providers tab and right-clik on free space. Then press “Add Group” and enter group name. Right-click on “Library” and press “Add JAR(s)”. Look in \ems\5.1\lib folder and select all .jar files there. Click “Open”, then let Hermes to scan jars for factories: press “Scan” button. Then press “Apply”. All libraries will be in the list like on my screenshot.

Go to “Sessions” tab and enter name for session: “My EMS” for example, then select “EMS” loader. Next step is select “com.tibco.tibjms. TibjmsConnectionFactory” class and “Tibco EMS” plugin. Order is very important: select loader, then class, then plugin. Right-click on free space in plugin section and press “Add property”. You have to enter all three properties: username, password and serverURL, do the same for Connection Factory, then press “OK” to save and close properties window.

Now we can connect Hermes to our EMS. Let it discover queues and topics, press “Discover queues and topics from the provider” button. Then confirm replacement of the current set of destinations and list will be updated. That’s all.